# Issue deserializing encrypted data using BinaryFormatter

Tags: c#, serialization, deserialization, binaryformatter, cryptostream

Here is my code:

```
    public static void Save<T>(T toSerialize, string fileSpec) {
        BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
        DESCryptoServiceProvider des = new DESCryptoServiceProvider();

        using (FileStream stream = File.Create(fileSpec)) {
            using (CryptoStream cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(stream, des.CreateEncryptor(key, iv), CryptoStreamMode.Write)) {
                formatter.Serialize(cryptoStream, toSerialize);
                cryptoStream.FlushFinalBlock();
            }
        }
    }

    public static T Load<T>(string fileSpec) {
        BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
        DESCryptoServiceProvider des = new DESCryptoServiceProvider();

        using (FileStream stream = File.OpenRead(fileSpec)) {
            using (CryptoStream cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(stream, des.CreateEncryptor(key, iv), CryptoStreamMode.Read)) {
                return (T)formatter.Deserialize(cryptoStream);
            }
        }
    }
```

Key and iv are both static byte arrays with a length of 8 which I'm using for testing purposes. There error is as follows:

> Binary stream '178' does not contain a valid BinaryHeader. Possible causes are invalid stream or object version change between serialization and deserialization

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Did you update windows or modify any other DLLs in your project between the time you called save and the time you called load?

Comment: @ScottChamberlain Yes, is there another method to do what I'm doing without regard for this? I'll be updating my application periodically.

Comment: Shouldn't `Load` be using `CreateDecryptor`, not `CreateEncryptor`?

Comment: `BinaryFormater` does not tolerate version changes, you are screwed. You are not supposed to persist data serialized by BinaryFormatter, you need to use XMLSeralizer or a 3rd party binary format like ProtoBuf. BinaryFormatter is only intended to be used for IPC communications.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain I originally was using XMLSerializer however I wasn't able to get it working with my classes as they're subclasses of a root class.

Comment: @Swizzbeat Well the reason BinaryFormatter works when XMLSeariazer does not is because BinaryFormatter will fail on deserialization if a class changes. Those more strict rules lets more stuff be serialized, but when you break the rules you get nothing back. BinaryFormatter may not have been your real problem *this time*, but it is going come back and bite you.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain What would you suggest I be using instead?

Comment: "you need to use XMLSeralizer or a 3rd party binary format like ProtoBuf. BinaryFormatter is only intended to be used for IPC communications."

Comment: @ScottChamberlain Thanks for the help, I'm looking into ProtoBuf now :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One small typo: your `Load` method should use `des.CreateDecryptor`, like this:

```cs
public static T Load<T>(string fileSpec)
{
    BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
    DESCryptoServiceProvider des = new DESCryptoServiceProvider();

    using (FileStream stream = File.OpenRead(fileSpec))
    {
        using (CryptoStream cryptoStream = 
               new CryptoStream(stream, des.CreateDecryptor(key, iv),
                                CryptoStreamMode.Read))
        {
            return (T)formatter.Deserialize(cryptoStream);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I can't believe I did that xD